# SonarQube community & enterprise editions

Tags: sonarqube

I have 5 different versions of SonarQube community editions which are going to be consolidated into a single enterprise edition.

1. Can the community and enterprise editions exist together in 1 portfolio(including different versions of community edition)?
2. Can the enterprise and community editions communicate with each other? Can the enterprise edition extract metrics from community edition,to be displayed on the dashboard in enterprise edition?

Comment: I get that this is a tool that developers use, but this feels like you should *really* be asking a Sonarqube representative instead.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If someone here would have done a similar consolidation, they can help too. Hence the question :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. Can the community and enterprise editions exist together in 1 portfolio(including different versions of community edition)?

Sure, why not? But they will be entirely independent of each other. This is like asking "Can I have multiple laptops in the same room?". :-)

> 2. Can the enterprise and community editions communicate with each other? Can the enterprise edition extract metrics from community edition,to be displayed on the dashboard in enterprise edition?

Not only can Enterprise and Community not communicate with each other, but SonarQube instances don't "communicate" at all (see #1).

However, since you talk of consolidating, *and* you're throwing "enterprise($)" into the mix, you should be able to use the [Project Move](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Project+Move)($) feature to *consolidate* some or all of your multiple instances. (Note that this is a multi-step operation: export from source, import into target, delete from source.) There are some restrictions on the move functionality: the source and target instances must be at the same version with the same commercial features and plugins, but this will allow you to consolidate your instances so that "communication" is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks much for your inputs! It's great to know about the Project move feature in Governance plugin. Thanks again!

Comment: @BharathiJebamalar if this answered your question or solved your problem, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Oh sure! Just did that @G. Ann .. I'm new to stack overflow and learning the terminologies only now :) Thanks again!

Comment: Ann does the Project “Move” operation perform a copy or cloning of the Project to the Enterprise Instance?  Or does this operation actually move that Project into the Enterprise Instance? I believe it creates a copy but just wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: If the projects are copied or cloned to the Enterprise Instance, it will still allow teams to still work on their local instance version! Since each application/team can have their own rules & quality profiles and map it to their respective sonar project, how are teams able to work on the Enterprise Instance Project version, if this Project gets defined as being a member of an Application and/or Portfolio and linked to a Quality Profile for Enterprise Metrics? As we know, a Project can’t be linked to 2 different Quality Profiles?

Comment: See my expansion @BharathiJebamalar

Comment: Just saw it: (Note that this is a multi-step operation: export from source, import into target, delete from source.) Thanks for this! Are all the 3 steps mentioned here, mandatory? What if we don't delete from source? Please guide!